# Setting Outlook email Expiry date/time from VBA (before sending the message) - External recipients

Tags: vba, email, outlook, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to send messages with an Expiry time from VBA. The code below is working if I am sending to myself or people in the same Organization within Office 365.  But, when I send to a person in a different organization (still has Office 365) - the Expiration doesn't come through.

Is there some workaround for that?  Or a way to set Retention period (I see in Outlook that I can set Retention period for individual emails I receive, but don't see how to set that in VBA).

Thanks!

```
Sub testEmail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set myMsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    'attach the document if NOT being uploaded OR if the "Attach Anyway" override = "Yes"
    If Sheet5.Cells(2, Sheet5.Range("FileShareLocation").Column) = "" _
          Or Sheet5.Cells(2, Sheet5.Range("AttachOverride").Column) = "Yes" _
       Then
            If Sheet5.Cells(2, Sheet5.Range("ZipFile").Column) = "Yes" Then
                myAttachments.Add strSaveToPath & strFileNameZip
            Else
                myAttachments.Add strSaveToPath & strFileName
            End If
    End If
    
    strSubject = "Test - expires " & Now + 30
    strBody = "Hello," & "<br><br>" & "Test - expires " & Now + 30
    
    With myMsg
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = strBody & _
            .HTMLBody 'last .HTMLBody includes signature from the outlook.''<br> includes line breaks b/w two lines
        .To = "Test@Test.com"
        .Subject = strSubject
        .ExpiryTime = Now + 30  'set it to expire in 30 days so the inbox doesn't stay junked up (especially if we're sending attachments)
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        '.Attachments = ThisWorkbook
        '.Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MailItem.ExpiryTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.expirytime) property returns or sets a Date indicating the date and time at which the item becomes invalid and can be deleted. The Outlook client does not include a way to auto-delete expired messages, but it does display them with strikethrough font modifier.

In case of the [MailItem.RetentionExpirationDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.retentionexpirationdate) property available in the Outlook object model, a Date that specifies the date when the `MailItem` object expires, after which the Messaging Records Management (MRM) Assistant will delete the item, not Outlook. A retention policy is enabled and disabled by an administrator for an Exchange Server on a mailbox level. This feature is available only on an Exchange mailbox with MRM version 2.0 or later enabled.

Microsoft Outlook calculates the value of this property based on the item retention start date and the retention period, if Outlook is in cache or offline mode. The Exchange Server specifies the value if Outlook is in online mode.

In general, the retention start date for the item is determined as follows:

- Received or sent items: the retention start date is the received date.
- Nonrecurring calendar items: the retention start date is the appointment end date.
- Recurring calendar items: the retention start date is the end date of last recurrence. If there is no end date, the item never expires.

Comment: Thanks!  That all makes sense - but when I send a message to myself with the ExpiryTime property set, Outlook shows me that date/time in the "Expires" column.  But - when I send it to an Office 365 account outside my domain - it is not shown - and the message does not get the cross-out effect after the designated time.  :(

Comment: I think that is a user-related question and not a subject for SO. I'd suggest posting non-programming questions on the superuser.com instead.